# Android Studio/LeadBolt SDK: Setting up sample SDK and sample App given files

Tags: android, leadbolt

I have been trying to understand how to incorporate a sample app from the LeadBolt SDK. LeadBolt is a mobile/web advertising service.
http://help.leadbolt.com/android-integration-guide/
I've downlaoded their SDK and I got an executable and a sample application, but when I open up the folder that has the .idea, lib, and src folders as my project, it doesnt automatically compile. I get errors in the XML that says that the URI is not recognized and that the version codes are not reconized in the manifest.

I want to be able to import sample apps but I'm failing on the developer side.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it compile for me. Heres what I did:

1) In android studio, go to file -> new -> import project

2) imported the LeadBoltSampleApp folder that was already unzipped

3) Gradle needed to be updated, in the 'app' box it asked to update the 'missing platforms'

([this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RwVvZtNTaM)) helped with step 3